# Does a wireless to wireless repeater have to know about encryption?

Tags: encryption, repeater

I am curious, whther a WLAN repeater needs to know about network encryption?
It works on the 1st level of OSI Model - why does TP-Link write [here](http://www.tp-link.fi/article/?id=151) that only WEP is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think a wireless repeater is a level 1 device? It's not a hub that emits received data to all other connected clients. It is in fact operating at layer 2 (MAC addresses).
In order to relay traffic it needs to be connected to another wireless accesspoint and accept new wireless clients, therefore requiring support for the encryption in use.